# How to get methane concentrations from MQ-4 sensor

Tags: esp8266, gas-sensor

I have an ESP8266 chip that is connected to an MQ-4 sensor. I need to get the concentration of methane in air, the problem is I can't find a way to convert the analog readings into ppm or any other concentration unit; the outputs are irrational.

```
const byte MQ4_Pin = A0; //MQ4 A0 pin
const int R_0 = 945; //Change this to your own R0 measurements

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   Serial.println(getMethanePPM());
   delay(2000);
}

/*
* getMethanePPM returns a float value in PPM of methane concentration
*/
float getMethanePPM(){
   float a0 = analogRead(A0); // get raw reading from sensor
   float v_o = a0 * 5 / 1023; // convert reading to volts
   Serial.print(v_o);
   float R_S = (5-v_o) * 1000 / v_o; // apply formula for getting RS
   float PPM = pow(R_S/R_0,-2.95) * 1000; //apply formula for getting PPM
   Serial.println("Methane ppm value: ");
   return PPM; // return PPM value to clling function
}
```

Comment: You should be dividing by 1024 rather than 1023. Are you certain that the supply voltage is 5 volts?

Comment: Use a voltmeter to measure the sensor output. Divide the problem.

Comment: yes @ElliotAlderson , I am sure it is 5V. But why 1024 not 1023

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ESP8266 have ADC that reads voltages between 0-1 V, so in this line

> float v_o = a0 * 5 / 1023; // convert reading to volts

there's a chance the ESP8266 is reading the maximum value it's ADC can measure

Comment: so what do you suggest, to remove this step?

Comment: I'm suggesting you check the range of the ADC of your ESP8266 (with two resistors) and the range of the possible voltages your sensor is outputting, so you know whether the ESP can read it or not